# Given a and b, find m such that a mod m = b mod m

Tags: algorithm, math, modulo

I am trying to solve a algorithmic problem, which has a sub-part which asks you to find an integer m such that for given two integers a and b, we get a mod m = b mod m.
mod is the modulo operation. How to approach this problem?

Comment: Will any choice of m do, or are you looking for the largest possible choice of m?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
          a mod m = b mod m
==> (a - b) mod m = 0 
==>         (a-b) = k * m    for some integer k
==>     (a-b) / m = k
```

So `m` can be any factor of `a-b` .

Comment: Thank you. Further curiosity: this may not give the smallest possible m, for example if a = 1 and b = 100 , we would get m as multiples of 99. however m = 3 would also work. Is it possible to get the smallest m?

Comment: @AyushLodha 3 is a factor of 99, so you can just use the smallest non-trivial divisor of `a - b`.

Answer (score 4):

we have to find any number such that `A % M == B % M`
now to satisfy this condition

1. we can assume without loss of generality `A > B` then  `B = A - (A - B)`
2. now we take mod on both sides it will become `B % M = (A - (A - B)) % M`
3. to reduce `(A-B)` from our equation we can replace M with `(A-B)`
4. our equation become `B % (A-B) = (A - (A-B)) % (A-B)` solving it futher it becomes `B % (A-B) = (A % (A-B) - (A-B) % (A-B))` as `(A-B) % (A-B) is 0`
5. so our final equation will becomes `B % (A - B) = A % (A - B)` which is same as given equation here `M = (A - B)` is our final answer

```
M = (A - B) if A > B 
M = (B - A) if B > A
```

Answer (score 2):

for greatest possible m

```
public int solve(int A, int B) {
   
   
    if(A>B){
        return A-B;
    }
        return B-A;

    }
```

**Runtime estimation 1433ms **